# Cannot Read Property of Undefined javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am checking to see if a string is a substring of another string in the array. Here is a piece of my index.js:

```
var state = [];
router.post('/doquery', function(req, res) {  
var input = req.body.input;
var tempState = [];
var i = 0;
console.log(input);
console.log(state);
console.log(state.length);
while (i < state.length) {

    if  ( ( ((state[i].name).indexOf(input)) !== -1 )  ||
         ( ((state[i].city).indexOf(input)) !== -1 ) ||
         ( ((state[i].country).indexOf(input)) !== -1 ) ||
         ( ((state[i].birthday).indexOf(input)) !== -1 ) ||
         ( ((state[i].email).indexOf(input)) !== -1 )||
         ( ((state[i].phone).indexOf(input)) !== -1  ) )  {

        tempState.push(state[i]);
    }
      i++;
}


res.render('doquery', {title: 'Doquery', tempState: tempState});
});
```

I get this error message: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. I understand that this means that state is not defined. But I did define it. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

**EDIT:** If it makes any difference, i also have this in my code:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
var obj = { name: req.body.name,
    city: req.body.city,
            country: req.body.country,
            birthday: req.body.birthday,
            email: req.body.email, 
            phone: req.body.phone };
state.push(obj);
res.render('add', { title: 'Person just added', item: obj });
});
```

state have the var obj in it.

Comment: Have you tried putting the var state into the router.post func?

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: I've tried on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mzh06d3/1/), and I'm getting no such error.  Are you sure it's not something to do with the routes?

Comment: @taesu the var state is also used by some other function and that is why it cannot be put inside the function

Comment: @nril this is what in the console: undefined
[ { name: 'natalie',
    city: '',
    country: '',
    birthday: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '' } ]
1
POST /doquery 500 238.362 ms - 1220
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 15.394 ms - -

Comment: Hey, you said "`state`" is used by another function, right?  What if you have a race condition or the function isn't in the right scope?  Can you post the other function?